# Is NTFS file system supported on Huawei u8160?

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb-host-mode, compatibility, huawei-u8160

I have a Huawei u8160 running Cyanogenmod 7.2 .

I have a 500GB portable hard drive which is file system is NTFS , I connected the hard drive using OTG the phone didn't recognize it at all.

So I was wondering if my Android system supports NTFS?

and if it doesn't how can I make it supported?

---

**EDIT:**

I've formatted a flash drive to NTFS ,the phone detected it but it couldn't mount it,how can I mount NTFS file system on my phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen any Android system supporting NTFS out-of-the-box. Could be some CustomROMs do, or there are some "root mods". So without root, it might get hard (though there might be some UserSpace mods as well, technically spoken).

If your device is rooted, you could take a look at [NTFS Mounter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kwull.ntfsmounter), which might or might not support your Huawai (take care to have a backup at hand anyway until you can be sure everything works as expected).

Moreover, there was an article at XDA-Developers in June on [Full NTFS Read/Write Support for Android](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/full-ntfs-readwrite-support-for-android/) you might want to read: *According to the OP, he compiled a generic NTFS-3G driver for Android that should work on all ARM devices with a `fuse.ko` module.* As it involves a kernel module to be loaded, it again requires root. And also again: It might or might not work on your device, take care for backups.

A third source is Paragon's [NTFS & HFS+ for Android](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-hfs-android/) (also available at [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paragon.mounter)). Paragon is quite well-known with disk utilities on Windows, so I'd trust them to get the NTFS part right. But as you might have guessed: This tool requires root as well, plus the above mentioned fuse module.

If you need more details, try the [Google Search for "android ntfs"](http://www.google.de/search?q=android+ntfs) where I got above results from, all on page 1 ;)