# where can I find fuse.ko file for my huawei u8160?

Tags: cyanogenmod, huawei-u8160, ntfs

I have a Huawei u8160 running Cyanogenmod 7.2 .

I have been looking for the fuse.ko module for my phone, but whenever I find anything ,terminal emulator tells me that it is incompatible!

I want it to enable NTFS file system support using this [tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=31624796)

So I was wondering where I can find the appropriate fuse.ko module?

**NOTE :** I've already seen this [link](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) but I don't think that's what I want.

Comment: This was answered in a comment on another [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/29461/4003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build that module yourself from the source code of the Linux kernel your device is running (presumably some Cyanogenmod kernel).

- You can find out which kernel your device is running, and with which compiler it was built, using `cat /proc/version`.  Try finding the corresponding kernel sources in the Cyanogenmod repositories.
- The kernel configuration file used to build your kernel (.config) should come with the kernel sources.  If you're lucky, you can dump it with `zcat /proc/config.gz` on your device.  Put the .config file into your source tree.
- Find a matching compiler.  Typically, one of the compilers coming with the NDK will be fine.
- If the kernel uses modversions, you first need to build the kernel to get the Module.symvers file right.  Assuming the NDK's cross compiler is in your path, try:

  ```
  make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-
  ```
- One you have a kernel, add the modules you need to the configuration by using the xconfig (or menuconfig) make targets:

  ```
  make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- xconfig
  ```
- Build the module.

  ```
  make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- modules
  ```

  If insmod'ing the module fails with an error saying that _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ was not found, try adding the -fno-pic option:

  ```
  make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- XTRA_CFLAGS=-fno-pic modules
  ```

Good luck.